# Generate DKIM for Gmail Free Account

Tags: email, smtp, email-server, gmail, dkim

I am using Gmail SMTP with wordpress to send mail with my custom domain `(user@example.com)`. Emails are successfully sent but always land in spam folder in every webmail provider (Eg, Gmail, Rediffmail, Yahoo, Outlook, etc)

```
Gmail SMTP server address: smtp.gmail.com
Gmail SMTP name: Your full name
Gmail SMTP username: Your full Gmail address (e.g. you@gmail.com)
Gmail SMTP password: The password that you use to log in to Gmail
Gmail SMTP port (TLS): 587
Gmail SMTP port (SSL): 465
```

This happen because of ***they couldn't verify the sender of this email***, and DNS record like SPF and DKIM. I googled and i got SPF record for Gmail `v=spf1 a include:_spf.google.com ~all`

But how to generate DKIM for my Gmail SMTP. I have checked this Google document : https://support.google.com/a/answer/180504#turn-on-dkim but it about the Google Business Mail/WorkMail not the Free Gmail (user@gmail.com).

Can you tell me how can i generate DKIM for my Gmail and How can i make my Email not stand in Spam folder.

My current DMARC `v=DMARC1; p=none` . I have noticed mail sent by ***Gmail SMTP*** says `DMARC Failed` in Email Header but my same record says `DMARC Passed` when it sent from ***ZohoMail***

**Email Header**

```
Return-Path: <mehul841@gmail.com>
Delivered-To: albertxpoland7@f6.p30.mail.in.rediffmail.com
X-DKIM-Verification: dkim domain= -; verify=2; NO Signature;
X-SPF-Verification: spf domain=gmail.com; result=pass; clientip=209.85.214.176; SAligned=0; RAligned=0;
X-DMARC-Verification: dmarc=none; dkim=fail; spf=fail; pct=100; domain=vpnsreview.net;
Received: (qmail 8648 invoked from network); 5 Jan 2023 18:08:13 -0000
X-IN-VDRT-SpamState: 0\LEGIT
X-IN-VDRT-SpamScore: 0
X-IN-VDRT-SpamCause: gggruggvucftvghtrhhoucdtuddrgedvhedrjeekgdduudduucetufdoteggodetrfdotffvucfrrhhofhhilhgvmecutffgfffkhffhnecuuegrihhlohhuthemuceftddtnecunecujfgurhephfffuffkvfggtgesrgdtreertddtjeenucfhrhhomheprhgrjhgvvghvsehsvghrvhgvrhhhuhhmphdrtghomhenucggtffrrghtthgvrhhnpedvfffgjeeuvefgvdffjeffgeduvdffhfelfffglefgkeegueejvdetleefjeejffenucfkphepheegrddvuddvrddufedurddukedunecuvehluhhsthgvrhfuihiivgeptd
X-Remote-IP: 209.85.214.176
X-REDIFF-SENDER-VERIFY: D=-2, DKIM=0, P=D
Received: from mail-pl1-f176.google.com (209.85.214.176)
by 0 with ESMTPS (AES128-GCM-SHA256 encrypted); 5 Jan 2023 18:08:13 -0000
Received: by mail-pl1-f176.google.com with SMTP id c2so12581044plc.5
for <albertxpoland7@rediffmail.com>; Thu, 05 Jan 2023 10:08:12 -0800 (PST)
X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
d=1e100.net; s=20210112;
h=mime-version:to:message-id:subject:date:from:x-gm-message-state
:from:to:cc:subject:date:message-id:reply-to;
bh=aRlsqpb4hDIgx52BOYVQ/7aDGi+GJMNlJXhhCWhfRw4=;
b=tSW41L95zzj5Czoj7UghYarvwA1pCbj5CjJ9ccrGt/0fZTOLRgntbx2nYoFJVLr+xF
rxm/qg07VVbkxObZ67BeTs9OKR4j8s8KcZK6QsiDdtzN2fwjC7tVOtbKLp3Y6r4j/7ml
mlJaXZyj2BocWlckKTf0Fk4U34nrCLBm+MFzSu1gte7dHwo76NQ3y18VvmBLL0jcs+JL
QEQY1y+JqAsZ+3egdTL1uUXCQ14e+DBf8vkjsEHTAS4BysYmKYqOqMS+rUhOZFNEeBYg
boUd/zMyOYV5BdfH45wOq/seAwJkGqbf98xEIvZT91cOv5pTPjpqCSNWEsmIMZg5g4Vt
N4+A==
X-Gm-Message-State: AFqh2kqcCcby96EW5MSximnYg/GH7FCREX70wK8ECjXDn1Vz/fKve6JV
KCl06/N1ZawcuZYxs+It4Dy5RRQTiaYqX4zU
X-Google-Smtp-Source: AMrXdXuIfyxf9/D9ZCdbcaT4IOZpKtwi+ColF32x3K8BwBv3Aszaqopihz7sVhCXXYwLP1C/Ob8Aww==
X-Received: by 2002:a05:6a21:2d05:b0:a7:92f2:9b65 with SMTP id tw5-20020a056a212d0500b000a792f29b65mr67293906pzb.59.1672942089426;
Thu, 05 Jan 2023 10:08:09 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <mehul841@gmail.com>
Received: from [172.31.11.248] (ec2-54-212-131-181.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com. [54.212.131.181])
by smtp.gmail.com with ESMTPSA id i2-20020a170902c94200b00189618fc2d8sm26355711pla.242.2023.01.05.10.08.09
for <albertxpoland7@rediffmail.com>
(version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
Thu, 05 Jan 2023 10:08:09 -0800 (PST)
From: mehul@vpnsreview.net
Date: Thu, 05 Jan 2023 18:07:59 +0000
Subject: SMTP test from smtp.gmail.com
Message-Id: <RGC9DV4EUIU4.H4YWENIPAQIO3@WIN-AUIR3RRGP88>
To: albertxpoland7@rediffmail.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="=-vPe7/WRdKCpdInodHv+yEg=="
```

Comment: Is your question for the domain `vpnsreview.net`?

Comment: @Paul Yes and testing some other domain too.

Comment: That domain's DNS records cannot currently support sending from anywhere. Your problems are beyond DKIM (the topic of this question). I recommend substantially revising or submitting a new question that describes the problem you are having without assuming something specific (such as DKIM).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know Gmail will not sign for custom domain when sending through free Gmail account.

In reality this should be YOU (meaning - your wordpress system) which does DKIM signing.

Without email headers it is hard to tell why exactly DMARC fails for your emails but I suspect this is because of lack of alignment between envelope (likely - your free gmail email address) and header sender (likely - your custom domain email address).

Comment: I know Gmail SMTP is not good solution but it Free and Easy. I have updated Email Header in question. Please check why DMARC Fails

Comment: Have a look at: https://www.appmaildev.com/en/dkimfile (paste the headers to the text box). In short - SPF is set to disable all sending from vpnsreview.net domain and DMARC fails because of that and missing DKIM signature as of now. Additionally Return-Path does not match with From and this as far as I remember would cause the abovementioned misalignment.

Comment: I'm not clear that Google will forward headers through the submission port.

Comment: I share Paul's worries. I would look at a free SMTP Relay provider that supports DKIM on custom domains. I'm not in any way affiliated, but know that SendGrid offers that with 100 free emails daily.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with a free Gmail account. It's only available to Google Workspace customers.

Sign up for Google Workspace or use an external SMTP server (create your own or use 3rd party email services).